# Cannot create a connection to data source

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, report

I am trying to access to rdl from sqlserver 2005 reporting server to ASP.net page.
But im screwed up with the following error.
""Cannot create a connection to data source"" I tried lot of things as advices by experts in the forum, but nothing working out for me.
Is there any solution for this prob ?
Thanks,

Comment: unless someone has a crystal ball, I suggest you provide more details...

Comment: Hi Mitch, Thanks for your response. Im using sql reporting server 2005  and created report using BIDS 2005. What im trying to do is, trying to launch the report in ASP.net page. In the asp.net page i used report viewer and embed the report path. when i run the application the ASP page throws the error as below.     An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)

Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSource1'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection) For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors ..

Comment: We are using sql server 2005 DB and front end code (ASP.net) in VS2010.

When i designed the report in 2005 and run the code it pop-up the error saying  

" Remote report processing requires Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services or later. "

We cant change the Sql server from 2005 to 2008 :(

 

Any Idea or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Have you provided the datasource to the report?  That appears to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one.

**you using SQLHelper.cs file in your project.
add connection string in web.config file in project.**

then write your aspx.cs page namespace like

```
using System
using System.Data;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Below code :

```
using system.data;
using system.data.sqlclient;
```